# Is there a list of formulas for geometric series?

Tags: summation, geometric-series

For example:

$1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

I'm sure there are many more but there doesn't seem to be any source that has a list of these formulas.

Comment: Your first example is an arithmetic, not geometric, series

Comment: Which one(s) are you interested in?

Comment: Both actually, I'm trying to solve recurrence equations and not everyone remembers formulas for a series of numbers.

Comment: @Code4life: you'd better phrase your question to be about *series*.

Comment: First hit upon search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series

Answer (score 0):

Well, for arithmetic sums:

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{n}x^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{n}x^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

Finally, an infinite series that is $a+ar+ar^2...=\displaystyle \frac{a}{1-r}$

Comment: It should be n in the RHS

Comment: @Tojrah thank you for catching that